# Question about dimension of the first cohomology group.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a smooth curve $C$ of genus $g$ over $k$, let $T_C$ denotes its tangent sheaf. What's the dimension of $H^1(C,T_C)$?

My professor said, by Riemann-Roch, $\text{dim} H^1(C,T_C)=3g-3$. But how to compute it explicitly? By definition, $T_C=Hom(\Omega_{C/k},\mathcal{O}_C)$. Using duality, $\text{dim}H^1(C,T_C)=\text{dim} H^1(C, \Omega_{C/k})$. Since $C$ is of dimension $1$, $\Omega_{C/k}$ is the canonical sheaf $K$. By Riemann-Roch, $\text{dim}H^0(C,\Omega_{C/k})-\text{dim} H^1(C,\Omega_{C/k})=degK+1-g=2g-2+1-g$. Then I can't proceed further. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made too many mistakes.

If $g=0$, $H^1(T_C)=0$. If $g=1$ one has $T_C\cong \Omega_C$ and then you have the dimension to be one and not zero. So, $3g-3$ is correct only if $g\geq 2$.

In that case, one has $\deg T_C=2-2g<0$ and so $H^0(T_C)=0$ and Riemann-Roch gives what you want.

Comment: Right! I forgot $g$ has to be bigger than $2$. But could you explain why deg$T_C=2-2g$? Is it because it's the dual of $K$?

Comment: Yes. Duals have negative of the degree.